# Dealing with conditional verification logic using guard assertion

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, conditions, assertions

I have  parametrized test with 2 variants:

- `NULL` value

and

- any `NOT NULL` value

From this value is depends one assert:

- In case `NULL` it should be checked if object has `field1` with `value1`
- In case `NOT NULL` it should be checked if object has `field2` with `value2`

As I mentioned (see *xUnit Tests Patterns* ) using conditional statements in assert is anti-pattern.

How can I solve this problem properly?

I am trying at the moment to apply Guard assertion pattern:

- `if`-assertion is splitted into 2 assertions
- At the beginning there is test parameter check (`NULL`/`NOT NULL`) with *guard assertion*:

  ```
  it('case describing conditionalParamter=NOT NULL'):
      expect(conditionalParamter, 'to be a', 'string') // Guard assertion which can FAIL test. Is it OK? Can I simply **SKIP** assertion WITHOUT test failing 
      expect(myStub.args, 'to satisfy', [[ nonConditionalParamter,  ExpressionWhichUsesNonNullConditionalParamterValue ]])

  it('case describing conditionalParamter= NULL')
      expect(conditionalParamter, 'to be falsy') // Guard assertion. The same issue
      expect(myStub.args, 'to satisfy', [[ nonConditionalParamter,  ExpressionForNullConditionalParamterValue ]])
  ```

But in this case we have 2 failed assertions. Is it appropriate solution?

Is there better ways to solve problem?

Comment: I have no idea how this particular unit testing framework works, but it sounds like you're saying it has a way of saying "use any non-null value for test 1 and null for test 2" and yet it does not have a way of saying "assert that this parameter was null (or not null)", which sounds massively broken to me. Is that the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what test framework you're using. But, this is what it might look like in RSpec (Ruby):

Method under test:

```
class Foo
  def bar(required_param, conditional_param = nil)
    return 'abc' if conditional_param.nil?
    '123'
  end
end
```

Tests:

```
describe Foo do
  subject(:foo) { described_class.new }

  describe '#bar' do
    subject(:bar) { foo.bar(required_param, conditional_param) }

    let(:required_param) { 'required_param' }

    context 'when conditional_param is nil (not present)' do
      let(:conditional_param) { nil }

      it 'returns abc' do
        expect(bar).to eq('abc')
      end
    end

    context 'when conditional_param is not nil' do
      let(:conditional_param) { true }

      it 'returns 123' do
        expect(bar).to eq('123')
      end
    end
  end
end
```